# Is there any Headless browser that supported by selenium with Downloading feature enabled

Tags: java, selenium, headless-browser

I want to press a few buttons using selenium to download a file for my testing process. This web page makes use of Javascript, so it is impossible to use something like HttpState in connection with Http client. I found that PhantomJs doesn't support this feature (Esspessialy on Linux). I use the following code with Firefox, but it is not headless.

```
 FirefoxProfile fprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
    String path;
    if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
        path = "/tmp/hon/";
    } else {
        path = "c:\\Downloads\\hon\\";
    }
    fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", path);
    fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application / zip");             fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    fprofile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
    mDriver = new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);
```

Is there any solution to use a construction like this with some headless browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [XVFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) X11 display server. It works in headless mode like a real display, you can take screenshots and other things.

Comment: I couldn't use this way, for few reasons. At least i need this solution crossplatform. i am looking for Headless browser, not Display server.